# CosmosDB latency after insert using mongodb api

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We have a C# method that will insert a document into CosmosDB (mongoDB Api) and then immediately perform a find for that document and its about 50/50 that it returns the document. It seems as if it is not fully completed in inserting the document even though it returns success. If the same find is ran again, it finds the document immediately. Has anyone else had these issues?
Here is our method..

```
newFederatedUser.Email = newFederatedUser.Email.ToLower();
FederatedUsers.InsertOne(newFederatedUser);
return FederatedUsers.Find(x => x.Email == newFederatedUser.Email).SingleOrDefault() != null;
```

Comment: Check to make sure that you don't have indexing set to "lazy" or "eventual". Can't remember which it is because I can't find the settings right now in mine. But when the indexing is not set to index immediately on insert (takes more RU and time for the insert), the indexing may not be complete for some unspecified amount of time.

Comment: That sounds right but for some reason I dont see the indexing options on the collections in the Data Explorer anymore. Gonna have to dig in a bit.

Comment: `newFederatedUser` should at least have its database id set after the insert one. I *think* that you could find it that way even without the indexing being ready. We have some collections set to lazy indexing to speed up the many inserts (as well as reduce the RU consumed). But then we need to "play games" with reads some times to make sure we get all of the records we need.

Comment: Yeah we will be having a mix of lazy and consistent collections in the end, depending on the business needs. Waiting on a support ticket from MS regarding the correct script to update the default index type without creating unique indexes since they have removed that portion from the portal.

Comment: OK so we have dug further and found that CosmosDB does not support changing the index policy for MongoDBApi. Their support has been lacking in telling how we can accomplish this.

Comment: That is crazy, as I've changed this in the past. I'm trying to get the time to test out an actual Mongo DB instance instead of this, and this is only one of the reasons.